# How to globally read in an auxiliary data file for a MapReduce application?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I've written a MapReduce application that checks whether a very large set of test points (~3000 sets of x,y,x coordinates) fall within a set of polygons. The input files are formatted as follows:

```
{Polygon_1 Coords} {TestPointSet_1 Coords}
{Polygon_2 Coords} {TestPointSet_1 Coords}
...
{Polygon_1 Coords} {TestPointSet_2 Coords}
{Polygon_2 Coords} {TestPointSet_2 Coords}
...
```

There is only 1 input file per MR job, and each file ends up being about 500 MB in size. My code works great and the jobs run within seconds. However, there is a major bottleneck - the time it takes to transfer hundreds of these input files to my Hadoop cluster. I could cut down on the file size significantly if I could figure out a way to read in an auxiliary data file that contains one copy of each TestPointSet and then designate which set to use in my input files.

**Is there a way to read in this extra data file and store it globally so that it can be accessed across multiple mapper calls?**

This is my first time writing code in MR or Java, so I'm probably unaware of a very simple solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using hadoop's distributedcache feature. [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html) is a facility provided by the Map-Reduce framework to cache files (text, archives, jars etc.) needed by applications.Google it and you can find code example.